# Laravel Homestead - Unable to create symlink on windows 10

Tags: vagrant, symlink, homestead, laravel-6.2

I run gitbash command as administrator on a windows 10 machine.

I navigate to the homestead directory: `cd homestead`

I start vagrant: `vagrant up`

I ssh into virtual machine: `vagrant ssh`

I navigate to project directory: `cd project1`

I run symlink command: `php artisan storage:link`

I get error:  `ErrorException  : symlink(): Input/output error`

Why is this not working?

Note I also update the vagrantfile inside the homestead directory by adding  this code to the following section:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  // other stuff

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
     v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
  end
end
```

Note I have also installed vagrant-winnfsd plug-in and have the following in my yaml file - not sure if that has any impact:

```
folders:
- map: c:\code\project1
  to: /home/vagrant/project1
  type: "nfs"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue and the solution was to **not SSH** into Vagrant or homestead and manually create the symlink from the host (win10)

From an Admin CMD or Git Bash go to /project1 root folder and run the following:

```
ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage
```

It will create a 'folder' (link file) ./public/storage that you can also browse with Windows Explorer, indistinguishable from a regular folder but with the same content as ./storage/app/public.

Also I notice you have:

```
folders:
- map: ~/code/project1
  to: /home/vagrant/project1
```

I don't think Windows understands ~ in the path.

You should map/sync a Windows folder to the VM folder. Mine looks like this:

```
folders:
    - map: C:/projects/
      to: /home/vagrant/projects
```

This way I'm able to access all of my projects that are under the C:/projects folder without having to setup each new one individually.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried what you said by running gitbash as administrator, going into the root directory and running the above command. A storage directory gets created inside the public folder. However whenever a file is saved to `storage/app/public` the same file does not appear inside `public/storage`?

Comment: @adam78 you're right. I just tried it and it didn't work. Maybe I didn't pay attention to what made it work. I was able to get it to work with the following `mklink /J .\public\storage .\storage\app\public` using regular CMD. You should see a chain icon next to the folder. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I've tried that too but using the `/D` flag instead of `/J` and that creates the symlink with chain icon but it doesn't propagate to the mapped folder inside homestead. If you SSH into homestead to the website directory you will see the public/storage folder is highlighted as red and you are unable to cd into it.

Comment: symlinks in ubuntu should be a blue colour